# Process in Linux

Tags: c, linux, process

I have an exercise in linux. When running this code.The result always executes the parent process before the child process. So I want to ask, is there ever a time when a child process prints out before a parent process?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("hello world (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
    int rc = fork();
    if (rc < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
        exit(1);
    } else if (rc == 0) {
        printf("hello, I am child (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
    } else {
        printf("hello, I am parent of %d (pid:%d)\n",
        rc, (int) getpid());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is possible, but unlikely because it takes time for the kernel to copy the process. You have no guarantees, however. If you want guarantees, then build them in.

Comment: @Cheatah I don't think the time for the kernel to "copy the process" makes any difference. That should have happened by the time `fork()` returns.